# MS Flow Not Posting File to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow, microsoft

Apologies as I'm very new to MS Flow, but my FLOW isn't properly posting daily reports I'm receiving to sharepoint.

[image]

[image]

Here is a screen shot of previous passed test with 365.[image]

Answer (score 0):

i created a same flow with your settings. An xlsx file in the email attachment is successfully written into the newly created file in SharePoint. Could you explain a bit more about your issue? You can simply click on your flow to see the flow history and check more detailed error message. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no error message. It passes the test but when I received the email in the past two mornings, the flow doesn't execute.

Comment: @zach So the flow is not triggered by the email. Have you checked the trigger settings? Especially the from and to email address, and the filter.

Answer (score 0):

> **NB:** Your flow is triggered only if the user email specified in **TO** receive email or in **From** has sent it, **Not daily**.